# Read/parse Simulink model information and insert in a graph database

Tags: parsing, neo4j, model, simulink

I have a MatLab Simulink project where I have several Simulink model (.slx) files. I want to do two things. First, I want to read/parse details information from these model files such as blocks, connected lines, source block and destination block of each connection, etc. Then, I want to insert these model information into a graph database (Neo4j). My ultimate goat is to visualize model information as nodes and relationships in Neo4j graph database. How can I read/parse the Simulink model information and then put in Neo4j database?

Thanks
Ibrahim

Comment: please share sample .slx files and what app/software you use to read it? Thanks.

Comment: You can consider this model (.slx) file as a simple example. [link](https://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/Content/Basics/buildex.slx). You can get more details about the model file in this [link](https://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?aux=Basics_Simulink).

I am not using any app/software. Actually I am looking for a solution to read it.

Comment: can you help me to screen shot the sample .slx that you gave?  We can help by giving you the neo4j model that is equivalent to that simulink then create the model/database for you.  I don't have mathlab to open that file.

Comment: Hi Jose, Here is the image of sample .slx file. [Image Link](https://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/Content/Basics/figures/SimulinkBasicsTutorial_BuildingSystems_FinalModel.png). You can get more details about the model file in this [link](https://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?aux=Basics_Simulink)

Answer (score 1):

Below is the script to create the model in neo4j;

```
MERGE (st:Block {name: 'step'})
MERGE (sm:Block {name: 'summation'})
MERGE (gn:Block {name: 'gain', below: 2.5})
MERGE (pi:Block {name: 'picontroller'})
MERGE (pl:Block {name: 'plant', `function`: "1/(s^2+2s+4)"})
MERGE (sc:Block {name: 'scope'})
With st, sm, gn, pi, pl, sc
MERGE (st)-[:TO]->(sm)-[:TO]->(gn)-[:TO]->(pi)-[:TO]->(pl)-[:TO]->(sc)
MERGE (pl)-[:TO]->(sm);
```

This is how the model will look like

[image]

And this is the query:

```
MATCH p = (n1:Block {name:'step'}) - [*] -> (n2:Block {name: 'scope'})
RETURN p
```

To remove everything in the model:

```
MATCH p = (n1:Block {name:'step'}) - [*] -> (n2:Block {name: 'scope'})
detach delete p
```

Comment: Hi Jose, Thanks for your answer and given time on this problem solution. This is the solution of the second part of my problem to insert the created cypher query. But for the first part of my problem, I need to find out a parser to extract information from the model files. I am looking for this parser now.